# Collection Post From JSP To Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, post, collections

how to post a collection (List of object) to servlet in jsp inside a form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP/HTML doesn't understand Java objects. You've to convert them to strings when putting them among the HTML and then convert them back when extracting them from the request parameters.

```
String yourCollectionAsString = getAsString(yourCollection);
request.setAttribute("yourCollectionAsString", yourCollectionAsString);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

with

```
<input type="hidden" name="yourCollection" value="${yourCollectionAsString}" />
```

and

```
String yourCollectionAsString = request.getParameter("yourCollection");
List<SomeObject> yourCollection = getAsObject(yourCollectionAsString);
```

A JSON parser like [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) may be useful here as it serializes and deserializes Java objects into a relatively compact String format in a single line of Java code (which is also reuseable for JavaScript in the client side, for the case that).

---

Alternatively, you can also store it in the session along with a long, unique, autogenerated ID and pass that ID around instead.

```
String yourCollectionID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
request.getSession().setAttribute(yourCollectionID, yourCollection);
request.setAttribute("yourCollectionID", yourCollectionID);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

with

```
<input type="hidden" name="yourCollectionID" value="${yourCollectionID}" />
```

and

```
String yourCollectionID = request.getParameter("yourCollectionID");
List<SomeObject> yourCollection = (List<SomeObject>) request.getSession().getAttribute(yourCollectionID);
request.getSession().removeAttribute(yourCollectionID);
```